# Meaning of [Correspondence] tag?

Tags: support, tags, meta

What is the meaning of the tag [correspondence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correspondence)?

Comment: For some reason I can't access the tag wiki on my phone, but presumably it refers to [correspondence](http://www.onelook.com/?w=correspondence&ls=a&loc=home_ac_Corre); that is, the art of letter writing (or communicating formally in some more abstract sense)?

Comment: I think Dan is right, but it doesn't look like a useful tag. It should probably be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me. ^_^